# Javascript String Array: Push method not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, list, push

I have a website that loads in songs for the user to play them. This method "loadSongs()" basically takes all the songs from a file input and is called "onchange" of the file input. I simply can't get the file names to get pushed into my string array called: "songs". Would appreciate any help, here is my code:

`function loadSongs() {`

```
var x = document.getElementById("file");
var songs = new Array();

if (x.files.length != 0) {

    for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {

        var file = x.files[i];
        songs.push(file.name);

    }

}

for (var j = 0; j < songs.length; j++) {

    alert("song #" + i + ": " + songs[i]);

}
```

}

I can successfully access the all the files in the first for loop because when I did "alert(file.name)" in the first for loop, it worked fine. I just can't get them into the string array unfortunately.

Comment: it should be `alert("song #" + j + ": " + songs[j]);`, not `i` in second loop.

Comment: And you should use browser [debugging](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) before asking such questions.

Comment: @Jacob You should respond to the comments and answers so that we know if your question has been answered.

Comment: Wow, I feel like I am an idiot, sorry guys for the waste of time. The thing is, browser debugging actually didn't pick this error up. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is not the `push` method, it is your `alert` parameters.

In the second loop:

```
for (var j = 0; j < songs.length; j++) {

    alert("song #" + i + ": " + songs[i]);

}
```

You have `"song #" + i + ": " + songs[i]`, but your loop is using `j` as the counter variable. Just change `i` to `j`.

```
for (var j = 0; j < songs.length; j++) {

    alert("song #" + j + ": " + songs[j]);

}
```

Comment: That's ok, just be sure to take Timur's advice and use the browser debugging to make sure the problem isn't something trivial.